# Unity3d Pause RigidBody object, don't stop time

Tags: unity, physics, timer

`Time.timeScale = 0` obviously works to stop physics but it's also stoping my `Invoke` calls. How can I get around this to pause ONLY the game physics?

**EDIT**

Temporarily I'm using `isKinematic = true` on all of my rigid body objects via event trigger.

Comment: watcha making? just curious

Comment: `Time.timeScale = float.epsilon;` is a hack that I have done in the past.

Comment: @Evorlor it's a limited augmented reality prototype. I want the scene to setup but keep all physics paused while the get-eady timer counts down at which point everything because active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off auto physics simulation:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics-autoSimulation.html

Or if you happen to be doing 2D:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D-autoSimulation.html